# How to get only distinct cities in the list?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `FrontEndController` that returns all conferences to the view.

```
class FrontEndController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('home')
            ->with('conferences', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(8)->get());
    }
```

In the view I have a part that I want to list all cities that exist for the existing conferences. For exmaple if there are 2 conferences in the database and one conference has the city Newcastle and another conference has the citiy Leeds I want to show in this list Newcastle and Leeds.

```
    <ul>
@foreach($conferences as $conf)
   <li>
       <a class="">{{$conf->city}}</a>
   </li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

The issue with this code is for example if there are 5 conferences in the city Newcastle, it appearss 5 times Newcastle but it should only appear once. Do you know how to properly solve this issue?

Maybe in the controller I can have something like:

```
->with('conferences', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->distinct()->get());
```

But its ok to have both

```
->with('conferences', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(8)->get());
```

and also

```
->with('conferences_cities', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->distinct()->get());
```

There are to many queries no? Or is ok? And if there are many conferences like thounsands maybe is slow to get all distinct cities of the congresses like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in the cities you can do :

```
->with('cities', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->pluck("city")->unique());
```

If you do this you need to change your front end to:

```
@foreach($cities as $city)
<li>
    <a class="">{{$city}}</a>
</li>
@endforeach
```

or for a slight performance boost (maybe) you can delegate to the database:

```
->with('conferences_cities', Conference::select("city")->orderBy('created_at','desc')->distinct()->get());
```

This will not require changes to your front end

A 3rd alternative would be :

```
->with('conferences_cities', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->unique('city'));
```

One more thing to note:

Long term it might be better to have a `cities` table like:

```
cities ( id, city )
```

and instead of city you can have

```
conference ( ..., city_id )
```

This means you can just select from cities directly instead of going via conferences

Comment: Thanks but with 3 solution instead of appaer the city name like "Newcastle", in each list item it appears: {"id":1,"name":"conf title","description":"",...}. Do you know why?

Comment: The 3rd solution will select everything and then will keep only entries with unique cities. In practice you will keep 1 row for each city . The row it keeps does not necessarily have any special relation to the city other than the fact that it was the first row to mention that city

Comment: Thanks, but with solution 1 "->with('cities', Conference::orderBy('created_at','desc')->pluck("city")->unique());
" the city name like "Newcastle" appears. With the solution 3 in the view should be     @foreach($conferences_cities->city as $city)?

Comment: I added an additional note to consider adding a relationship between conferences and a separate city table if you are concerned about having too many conferences and not that many distinct cities.

Comment: No, 1 city per conference but possibly many conferences can be held in the same city.